# foverlaps over 2 columns - 2 criterias

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using foverlaps to join 2 tables by the values of one column. The issue I'm facing is that I'm hitting the limit on the number of rows (getting "negative length vectors are not allowed" error).
The way I could resolve it (my plan) is by introducing a new criteria when doing the matching.

DT1

```
Mass Time <min mass> <max mass>
100  0    100 - tol   100+tol
101  0    101 - tol   101+tol
100  1    100 - tol   100+tol
101  1    101 - tol   101+tol
100  2    100 - tol   100+tol
101  2    101 - tol   101+tol
```

library

```
Mass    Time    <other cols>  <min mass> <max mass> 
100.1   0.5                   100.1      100.1     
100.9   0.9                   100.1      100.1
```

I'm keying the 2 DTs by min max mass and I'm running foverlaps(DT1, library). All works correctly when not hitting the limit.

Is there a way of using 2 criteria when doing the foverlaps? Or how should I think about the problem?
What I'm doing in excel to do the matching is something like:

DT1

```
Mass Time <min mass> <max mass> <min Time>      <max Time>
100  0    100 - tol   100+tol   0 - timeTol     0 + timeTol
101  0    101 - tol   101+tol   0 - timeTol     0 + timeTol
100  1    100 - tol   100+tol   1 - timeTol     1 + timeTol
101  1    101 - tol   101+tol   1 - timeTol     1 + timeTol
100  2    100 - tol   100+tol   2 - timeTol     2 + timeTol
101  2    101 - tol   101+tol   2 - timeTol     2 + timeTol
```

library

```
Mass    Time    <other cols>  <min mass> <max mass> <min Time> <max Time>
100.1   0.5                   100.1      100.1      0.5        0.5
100.9   0.9                   100.1      100.1      0.5        0.5
```

Comment: I am inferring from your data that in `librarY` variable mass = min mass = max mass and time = min time = max time. If that is correct, you can do a non-equi join. something like `librarY[DT1, on=.(Mass>=min_mass, Mass<=max_mass, Time>=min_time, Time<=max_time)]`

Comment: still get the same error, so I need to keep redefining my intervals. still, this solution is really slow compared with foverlaps.

Comment: Does your foverlaps works on 2 overlapping intervals?